# android - setting presentation time of mediacodec

Tags: java, android, encode, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer

I used bellow code to encode raw data to h264 in order to create video and it's encoded very well but video is playing too fast. It seems that there is a problem with presentation time. when record starts I set the value of "tstart" and for each frame calculate difference of current time from tstart and pass it to the queueinputbuffer but nothing has changed. which part has problem ? I know that in android 4.3 I can pass surface to mediacodec but I want to support android 4.1. thanks in advance.

```
 public void onPreviewFrame(final byte[] bytes, Camera camera) {
                    if (recording == true) {
                        long time = System.nanoTime();
                        time -= tstart;
                        if(mThread.isAlive()&&recording == true) {
                            encode(bytes, time );

                        }

                    }
 }

private synchronized void encode(byte[] dataInput,long time)
{
    byte[] data=new byte[dataInput.length];
    NV21toYUV420Planar(dataInput,data,640,480);

    inputBuffers = mMediaCodec.getInputBuffers();// here changes
    outputBuffers = mMediaCodec.getOutputBuffers();

    int inputBufferIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(-1);

    if (inputBufferIndex >= 0) {
        ByteBuffer inputBuffer = inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];
        inputBuffer.clear();
        inputBuffer.put(data);
        time/=1000;
        mMediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, data.length, time, 0);

    } else {
        return;
    }

    MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
    int outputBufferIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);
    Log.i("tag", "outputBufferIndex-->" + outputBufferIndex);
    do {
        if (outputBufferIndex >= 0) {
            ByteBuffer outBuffer = outputBuffers[outputBufferIndex];
            byte[] outData = new byte[bufferInfo.size];
            outBuffer.get(outData);
            try {
                if (bufferInfo.offset != 0) {
                    fos.write(outData, bufferInfo.offset, outData.length
                            - bufferInfo.offset);
                } else {
                    fos.write(outData, 0, outData.length);
                }
                fos.flush();
                Log.i("camera", "out data -- > " + outData.length);
                mMediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false);
                outputBufferIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo,
                        0);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (outputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
            outputBuffers = mMediaCodec.getOutputBuffers();
        } else if (outputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
            MediaFormat format = mMediaCodec.getOutputFormat();
        }
    } while (outputBufferIndex >= 0);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't write the output frames into a container that actually stores any timestamps at all. You are writing a plain H264 file, which only contains the raw encoded frames, no index, no timestamps, no audio, nothing else.

In order to get proper timestamps for the files, you need to use `MediaMuxer` (which appeared in 4.3) or a similar third party library (e.g. libavformat or similar) to write the encoded packets to a file. The timestamp of the output packet is in `bufferInfo.presentationTime`, and in the `if (outputBufferIndex >= 0) {` clause, you don't use it at all - you are basically throwing away the timestamps.

Comment: so what is presentationTimeUs which is forth parameter of queueinputbuffer function ?

Comment: That is the presentation time of the input frame. In most/all cases, it is not actually included in the encoded data, it is only brought along with the encoded frame so that you know what timestamp the encoded packet corresponds to. When writing the encoded packet into a file, you need to supply it (`bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs`) to the file (give it to the MediaMuxer API, or to the other library you use for writing your video files).

Comment: @SajadNorouzi Packets don't have to come out of the encoder in the same order they went in. So if the timestamp wasn't passed along, you could have trouble matching the timestamp to the output packet.